# nchar counts twice special characters in a shinyapp

Tags: r, special-characters, shiny, counting

I am trying to implement my first shinyapp:

http://juliomulero.shinyapps.io/micro2/

It is an app for a literary contest that takes into account the number of characters of the words in an spanish sentence which has to be the same of the decimals of pi.

In the third tag of the shinyapp, you can see what I want: people can write a sentence and shiny counts the characters of the words.

My problem is that when there is an accented word, the shinyapp counts one character more, for example, if I write "aquí" (which is "here" in spanish), the shinyapp counts 5 characters.

My code is the following:

```
output$micros<-renderText({
gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", input$micro)
})
output$cantidadpalabras<-renderText({
length(strsplit(input$micro,' ')[[1]])
})
output$caracteres<-renderText({
nchar(strsplit(gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", input$micro),' ')[[1]])
})
```

When I run the app with runApp(".") in my computer, it works fine, but when I deploy the shinyapp, it does not work.

I do not know if you can help me... I woulf be very grateful because I think this is a very powerful tool for my job.

The sessionInfo() output is:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Spain.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Spain.1252L 
C_MONETARY=Spanish_Spain.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Spanish_Spain.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.0.1
```

Thank you very much,
Julio

Comment: My first guess would be an issue with your locale setting on the machine running the shiny app. Can you include the output of `sessionInfo()` in your question? I ask, because `nchar` is counting 4 characters on my machine on the word "aquí".

Answer (score 2):

I have finally solved the problem, I added this before the shinyServer function:

```
encode <- function(x){
Encoding(x) <- "UTF-8"
x
}
```

and, then, I have forced the encoding:

```
nchar(strsplit(gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", encode(input$micro))," ")[[1]])
```